# how to install from the output of conda dependency export

Tags: python, anaconda, dependencies, conda, miniconda

I generated **dependency list** using:

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

Here are some parts of the `depency` file:

```
transformers=4.28.1=pypi_0
typing-extensions=4.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
typing_extensions=4.7.1=py310hecd8cb5_0
tzdata=2023.3=pypi_0
```

In a different conda environment, I am tryign to install a specific package with:

```
conda install transformers=4.28.1=pypi_0
```

But I get thsi **error**:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - transformers==4.28.1=pypi_0

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `=pypi_0` indicates that this package was installed using `pip`, not `conda`.

The underlying issue is that `conda list -e > requirements.txt` is not the correct command to export your environment for recreation.

That would be

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

or, even cleaner in most situations, :

```
conda env export --from-history > environment.yml
```

Which can then be recreated as an environment on another machine, or alternatively be passed to `conda install -f`